# Tag friend as "with—" on Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tagging

I forgot to tag a friend as "with—" on a two-photos post. The post got likes and comments so I cannot delete/repost. I tagged the friend on the single photos, but on my wall it has not the "with <friend name>" caption.

If I `GET /v2.1/<post-id>/tags`:

```
GET /v2.1/<post-id>/tags
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

where on another post with tagged friends I get:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "<friend-id>", 
      "name": "<friend-name>"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "<friend-id>", 
      "name": "<friend-name>"
    },
    …
}
```

Can I tag my friend via Graph API?

Comment: No, you can not tag in normal posts via API. Only Open graph stories allow tagging/mentioning.

Comment: That's a pity… I see no problem on permit this.